# Admob/ Play services integraiton. Cannot resolve symbol error

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, admob, google-play-services

i followed [this](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/quick-start) tutorial to integrate admob in Android Studio. But now in the MainActivity AdFragment class a few symbols are red (**word* *) (Cannot resolve Symbol) and there is nothing in the error log.

```
   public static class AdFragment extends **Fragment** {

    @Override
    public **View** onCreateView(**LayoutInflater** inflater, **ViewGroup** container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.**inflate**(R.layout.fragment_ad, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle bundle) {
        super.**onActivityCreated**(bundle);
        AdView mAdView = (AdView) getView().**findViewById**(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }

}
```

Also in the activity_main.xml

```
<fragment android:name="com.appname.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
```

PlaceholderFragment is red

My import statements:

```
package com.example.admobexample;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
```

Comment: Post your import statements and your package name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to use an IDE like AndroidStudio you'd have a neatly underlined classes that need to be imported, in order to be used. Also a handy shortcut to import them quickly.

Basically you are missing multiple import statements for example:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

You can Google the rest by yourself, if you still don't want to use an IDE.

---

Also in your xml file you didn't change the obvious `com.appname` to your package name. It should be:

```
android:name="com.example.admobexample.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
```

Of course make sure your `MainActivity` contains a static class called `PlaceholderFragment`, for the above to work.

Comment: Okay thanks i imported the classes and now it works. But i use Android Studio and there is no button to import these classes automatically.

Comment: @user2880114 in AndroidStudio, put your text cursor on the class in question and press ALT+Enter.